# How to build timidity for iPhone or how pay midi

Tags: iphone

In my project I should use midi file, but iphone can't play them. I found out that Timidity++ library may be portable to iphone. I downloaded source and tried to build it use build_for_iphoneos.sh script, but always have error - "build_for_iphoneos.sh: line 119: ./configure: No such file or directory".

Any one, please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `./configure` is missing, check if the file really is missing or if it is in another directory.

Comment: I checked but file or folder with this name does not exist in sources. Also I open build_for_iphoneos.sh which used for compiling static library for iphone and found this strings: ./configure \ --prefix="${prefix}" \ --host="${arch}-apple-darwin" \ --disable-shared \ --enable-static \ "$@" || exit

Comment: Well then, that's your problem. You should probably tell whoever made the `build_for_iphoneos.sh` script.